# cheese laggy webcam

Tags: camera, lag

My issue is when i want to take a pic using my webcam. The webcam image is really slow and laggy, but it used to work fine, maybe was an update or something, I tried my cam in omegle It worked fine.

Any clues?

*I use Peppermint OS (Lubunt based distro)

Comment: If you say that you used it and it worked fine with Omegle, what doesn't work fine?  Did you check the system's load while it's not fine with tools like `top`?

Comment: Already checked, just happen with Cheese, I use Gnucview (that does the same  functions of Cheese) and is working fine. But now I'm curious what happened.

Comment: Did you check `top`?